# How to find the latest created record using loopback REST API

Tags: rest, loopbackjs, loopback

Is there a way (a better way) to get the latest created record from database using [loopback](/questions/tagged/loopback) REST API?

I can get the latest created record by sorting the `created` property in descending order, and get the first object from the result. This is what I have now:

```
[GET] http://localhost:3335/v0/contracts?filter[order]=created DESC
```

but this returns the whole `contracts` modal records, is there a way to return only one single latest record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [GET] http://localhost:3335/v0/contracts?filter[order]=created DESC&filter[limit]=1